# Confused on what to do after catching exception

Tags: java, loops, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I am a little confused on what do after the catch statement in my code. After the exception is thrown and caught in the loop, the loop becomes infinite. I also found that entering a very long sequence (+10 or so) of numbers will cause the loop to go infinite. I am fairly new at exception handling in java, so a detailed description would be very educational.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean cont = false;

          while (!cont)
        {
            addInputNumber();
            cont = tryAgain();
        }
}


  private static void addInputNumber ()
  {
    boolean valid;
    int total;
    int inputInt;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a number(between 0 and 1000)");
            inputInt = input.nextInt();

            if(inputInt > 0 && inputInt < 1000)
                {
                    valid = true;

                    total = (inputInt % 10) + ((inputInt / 10) % 10) + (inputInt / 100);

                    System.out.println("\n" + "The total of " + inputInt + " is " + total);
                }

            else
                {
                    System.out.println("\n" + "ERROR---ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 1000" + "\n");
                    valid = false;
                }
        }

        catch(InputMismatchException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + "ERROR---ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 1000" + "\n");
            valid = false;
        }
    } while(!valid);
}
```

Comment: change the valid to true in the catch bock.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 catch(InputMismatchException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + "ERROR---ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 1000" + "\n");
        valid = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the catch block, your variable valid was set to false.
Then on the code

```
while(!valid)
```

The condition will be true, and the loop go infinite

Answer (score 0):

Your do while loop must end with

```
 while(valid);
```

Because, once you catch the exception `valid` becomes `false`, and you may want to exit the loop if the exception is caught

Comment: is iterating the loop after throwing the exception bad?

Comment: I will not call it bad, unless you dont have full control over what you are doing. If you have such requirements you have to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

What does the method `tryAgain()` do?
It looks like it calls `addInputNumber()`, right? If so, you don't need the loop in within the method `addInputNumber()`.
I think you're problem is not of what to do in the catch block, but of program structure. You're using two loops, and you probably just need one. You could have `addInputNumber()` to return a boolean.